# How to get the latest downloaded file name with applescript programatically?

Tags: applescript

I need to get the file name programatically on Mac, am using Selenium to download the file and from downloads folder i need to pick the same file to install programatically, am using Applescript to do the same. I am stuck in getting the file name in runtime, also my download page url doesnot contain full name of the download file. Pls suggest..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the latest file (sorted by creation date) of your downloads folder:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set latestFile to item 1 of (sort (get files of (path to downloads folder)) by creation date) as alias
    set fileName to latestFile's name
end tell
```

Comment: Just some feedback on this: seems to be doing the opposite in Mavericks, giving the oldest files, not the newest. Sad panda...

Answer (score 1):

Yes Mavericks does open the oldest, but this seams to work by specifying the last item.

`tell application "Finder"
    set latestFile to last item of (sort (get files of (path to downloads folder)) by creation date) as alias
    set fileName to latestFile's name
end tell`