# Scan a folder for a newly added file

Tags: macos, applescript

How do you scan a folder for newly added files using applescript.

I am trying to identify the newest files (picture formats) within a folder, from the previous time it has been inspected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want some script which, when you run it, will give you all files that are "new." Where "new" means the script has not seen them previously.

So if you run the script on a directory with files a.txt, b.txt, and c.txt, you would get all 3 of those files back from the script. Then before you run it again, files d.txt and e.txt are added, then you run your script, you should get both d.txt and e.txt.

In order to accomplish this you will need to store some information between runs of the script. For example you might create a hidden file .lastFileISaw and store in it the last filename or its timestamp. Then your applescript cna check for this file, if it's not there, return all files in the dir, if it is there return only those more recent than the contents of your hidden file.

I think services like Dropbox and SparkleShare utilize DTrace on OSX to accomplish these kinds of things.

Comment: The OP asked how to "identify the newest file" (singular). To me (and Lauri) that does not mean all files (plural) that the script has not seen already.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that was is poorly worded.

Answer (score 0):

`do shell script "ls -t ~/Pictures | head -n1"` would print the basename of the newest file.

This would print the full path:

```
find ~/Pictures -depth 1 -exec stat -f "%m %N" {} \; | sort -n | tail -n1 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //'
```

Comment: this is only in the /Pictures folder, right?  I am  trying to use it to find the newest file (which happens to be a picture file).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another aproach. You may change the downloads folder path to the path of your target folder.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set latestFile to item 1 of (sort (get files of (path to downloads folder)) by creation date) as alias
    set fileName to latestFile's name
end tell
```

[How to get the latest downloaded file name with applescript programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973026/how-to-get-the-latest-downloaded-file-name-with-applescript-programatically)

Comment: It sounds to me that he wants to know about files he hasn't seen before, in your approach, he just gets the most recent file, which could be a file he has already learned of (through previous run of this script) or, it could skip files if several are added between runs of this script.