# AppleScript - Get the name of the only file in a folder?

Tags: macos, file, applescript, directory, getfiles

The following AppleScript code gets the file that was added last,

```
tell application "Finder"
    set latestFile to item 1 of (sort (get files of (path to downloads folder)) by creation date) as alias
    set fileName to latestFile's name
end tell
```

*Source:* [How to get the latest downloaded file name with applescript programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973026/how-to-get-the-latest-downloaded-file-name-with-applescript-programatically)

But this fails if the folder has only one file. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is supposed to work with **one** file. But it throws an error if there is **no** file.

You can ignore the error with a `try` block

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set latestFile to item 1 of (sort (get document files of (path to downloads folder)) by creation date) as alias
        set fileName to latestFile's name
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you. How can we specify a path like this "/MainFolder1/SubFolder1"?

Comment: Strictly spoken `/MainFolder1` is on the top level of the startup disk. Is this intended? The Finder expects (colon separated) string paths starting with the name of a disk (also startup disk). You can write `get files of folder "Macintosh HD:MainFolder1:SubFolder1:" ...`

Comment: Thank again. You were very helpful.